# How to Connect the Spring Boot application with secured ActiveMQ via Apache Camel

Tags: java, spring-boot, apache-camel, activemq-classic

Although I have provided the user name and password of ActiveMQ in my `application.properties` file my Apache Camel ActiveMQ is reading the default username(admin) only and it is giving error like this "Cause: User name [admin] or password is invalid"

So, how can I configure ActiveMQ in Apache Camel so that it takes the updated value?

Answer (score 1):

If you're using ActiveMQ Artemis with Spring-boot and Apache Camel you can use

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.camel.springboot</groupId>
    <artifactId>camel-jms-starter</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-artemis</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Then you can add following properties to your `application.properties` and `spring-boot-starter-artemis` should create you a connection factory with given settings.

**Example application.properties:**

```bash
spring.artemis.mode=native
spring.artemis.host=localhost
spring.artemis.port=PORT
spring.artemis.user=username
spring.artemis.password=Password
```

If you're using the older ActiveMQ then you can use the `spring-boot-starter-activemq`

```xml
<!-- according to the documentation camel-jms should work as well -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.camel.springboot</groupId>
    <artifactId>camel-activemq-starter</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-activemq</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

**Example application.properties:**

```bash
spring.activemq.broker-url=tcp://localhost:PORT
spring.activemq.user=username
spring.activemq.password=Password
```

You can find more about spring-boot and jms using ActiveMQ and ActiveMQ Artemis from the [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.0.x/reference/html/boot-features-messaging.html#boot-features-jms)

Tested the ActiveMQ Artemis part with my dockerized ActiveMQ Artemis instance using host localhost and port 61616 and it seemd to work fine with Camel 3.20.2.

Versions for starters are handled by `camel-spring-boot-bom` for 3.20.2 and `spring-boot-dependencies` 2.7.8 and project was generated with `camel-archetype-spring-boot`.